# AWS Glue job to pull the data from DynamoDB in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

Im using AWS Glue to copy data from DynamoDB to S3. I have written the below code to copy DyanmoDB table to S3 in the same account. It works fine, copies my table with 600million records without any issues. It take about 20min.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from datetime import datetime

# inputs
dataset_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d')
table_name = "table-name"
read_percentage = "0.5"
output_location = 's3://'+dataset_date
fmt ="json" 

# glue setup
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)

# scan the DDB table
table = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options("dynamodb",
                                                  connection_options={
                                                                      "dynamodb.input.tableName": table_name,
                                                                      "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent": read_percentage,
                                                                      "dynamodb.splits": "100"
                                                                      }
                                                )

# write to S3
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=table,
                                         connection_type="s3",
                                         connection_options={"path": output_location},
                                         format=fmt,
                                         transformation_ctx="datasink"
                                        )
```

But now I want to do a cross account S3 dump using the above script. The DynamoDB tables are in account A (prod account) and the Glue job to read from DynamoDB tables and S3 bucket to dump that data are in Account B (DW account). I don't know if it is possible to use my script but give cross-account Glue access so it can read DynamoDB tables from Account A

Answer (score 0):

Create an IAM role in Account A (*DynamoDB table owner* account) that allows for Glue as *Principal* to read tables.

Configure permissions policy for IAM role in Account A (*DynamoDB table owner* account) that allowing reading data in tables. A sample you can build from is provided as follow:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListAndDescribe",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:List*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeLimits",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTimeToLive"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllTables",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Get*",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/table-1",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/table-2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Configure trust policy in the above IAM role in Account A (*Dynamo DB tables* account) to permit Glue to assume it.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

In IAM role configured for Glue job in Account B (which doesn't own the tables),
include a permission policy for it to assume the IAM role in Account A (*Dynamo DB tables owner* account).

```
    {
        "Sid": "DelegateDynamoDBTablesOwnerRoleArn",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::dynamo-db-table-owner-role-arn:role/*"
    }
```

#### References

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/cross-account-access.html#cross-account-calling-etl

Comment: the problem is not with the bucket policy. im trying to access the dynamodb table in account B, while my Glue job and S3 destination are in Account A

Comment: My bad, I'll revise my answer to reflect this understanding.

Comment: @LisaMathew Need your help ! I am trying read data from dynamo db table using the code you have posted here. I my Jupyter notebook , I am getting error after running the following 2 lines.  sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc). An error was encountered:
Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=livy-session-9, master=yarn) created by __init__ at /mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1602527659009_0010/container_1602527659009_0010_01_000001/tmp/7416680492502689723:589

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this going to work with the glue script running in the DW account.

The GlueContext connects to DynamoDB using the table name:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb

What you should explore is run the glue script in the **Prod** account and give cross-account access to your DW buckets so that Glue running in the prod account can assume the role to write the target S3 Buckets in **DW account**.

Comment: I got it working using the GlueContext configuration settings `conf=SparkConf()
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf))
spark=glueContext.spark_session
sc=spark.sparkContext
glueContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("dynamodb.awsAccessKeyId", "xvczxcvzcvzcxvxzcv") 
glueContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("dynamodb.awsSecretAccessKey", "xcvzcvzxcvzcvxzc+EBDFc2L0F") `

Comment: Let me tell you something that's weird about this. It's perfect that the job is working.  I'm a little uneasy with permanent credentials instead of a temporary session token. I'm pretty sure it's not easy because ```glueContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("dynamodb.awsSessionToken", "<token>") probably won't work.``` I wonder how to take this just a little further with a temporary STS session in an aws glue job that reads from DynamoDB, it won't hurt.

Comment: Yes, @starpebble. I agree with you. I think Amazon would change the GlueContext to support roles instead of credentials.  Depending on the implementation, it is possible to call the sts assume-role and get temporary credentials. But it is not the best experience indeed.

Comment: Yup. @AndersonMarques, kinda looks like a lot of indirection in AWS Glue. Hadoop and Spark have nifty credential provider classes. boto3 kinda supports STS tokens too. The AWS Glue context is kinda getting in the way.